# RemoveChild and CreateElement

Tags: asp.net

I need to combine the InnerText. I'm trying to get the all the InnerText from all the `<tr>`, remove all the `<tr>` and `<td>` tags, create 1 `<tr>` and `<td>`, then add the combined InnerText.

```
HtmlNodeCollection trNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr");
foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode trNode in trNodes)
{
    txt += trNode.SelectNodes("//td")[0].InnerText;
    txt += "<br />";
    tableNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(trNode, false);
}
tableNode.AppendChild(htmlDoc.CreateElement("tr"));
tableNode.AppendChild(htmlDoc.CreateElement("td"));
htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td")[0].InnerText = txt;
```

Comment: `tableNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(trNode, false);`
IS this necessary ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need XmlNode.InnerText property. 
Read complete information http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.innertext.aspx

It gives concatenated innerText for all child nodes.